# Can two different sites running on same host, share same database for storage and retrieval?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wiki

I am building a personal site, for blog i wish to use [wordpress](http://wordpress.org) and for a wiki i will use 
[wikia](http://wikkawiki.org/). Is it possible that i use the same database for storing articles from both the frontends (wordpress and wiki). If yes can i some how populate articles from my wiki to the blog, under a specific category.

EDIT - I actually want that, my blog and wiki, both can populate same articles. I am a systems developer, I donot know how to explain you in MySQL/PHP technical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question.
I would of thought you could store both systems in one database although it might get large, you could simply give each system a different table prefix

for example wordpress wp_ and wikia wk_

But im not sure if I am getting your questions right...do you want to make both system save to the same table(s)? or just have both system use one database?

Comment: I actually want that, my blog, and wiki, both can populate same articles. I am systems developer, I donot know how to explain you in MySQL/PHP technical terms.

Answer (score 4):

yes - very much possible, but most probably you'll need to have some custom data synchronization script. probably those two use completely different table layout and possibly different markup language.

you probably will need to hack a script that knows which articles in wordpress are done based on wiki and re-write them once every x hours based.

Answer (score 0):

Wikia and Wordpress store their content in entirely different methods in the database, so on the surface the answer is no.
About the only way to get around it is to write a script that synchronises the two data sources, converting from one format into the other format.  Whilst it would be possible, if you're wanting it to be a two way thing it'd be tricky to guarantee you were making the right changes in the right order, and you'd almost certainly have to give up on any notion of consistency.

Your question gives us how you're planning on providing some function, but what is it exactly that you want to provide?  A blog that is editable by joe public (or users with logins?)

I think we could probably help you best by offering suggestions about how to achieve what you'd like to achieve, rather than how to make your idea of a solution work.